# List All Google Spaces a user is a member o, including outside the orgnisation

Tags: google-api, space, google-workspace, google-chat

I have implemented a Chat Bot from the Google API and can post messages to all spaces that the bot allowed user is a member of.

However when I use the https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/list call do display a listing of all spaces that user is a member of, it does not show spaces outside of the organisation.

Is it possible to list ALL spaces a user is a member of including ones outside of their organisation?

Comment: Is this question programming related or just workspace related? please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a massive privacy law violation. So be happy it's not possible.

Comment: Yeh, when you put it that way....
Thanks.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo no, it is a privacy problem. Say I have a google account, now an organisation gets added to that account. By your logic that means that organisation now has complete access to my account, can see everything I do with it.